# Checking if a given program is running

Tags: raspbian, ssh, internet, script

Is there a way to check if a named program is currently running on an RPi? I am currently running my RPi headless with a VNC server over LAN to initiate the program and check it from time to time when I'm at home.

Now, I have SSH access to my device from anywhere and I wish to see if my script is running. Is there a way to do it?

Also is it possible to see the print values of that script running in the terminal?

The program runs on Raspbian OS on RPi 3.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI you should check the latest series on the blog (re: SSH) I am currently working on the SSH security section.

Answer (score 5):

@SteveRobillard answered my question in the comments. I will re-iterate it here for everyone to see clearly!

**1. Viewing running programs:**

In the terminal type: `ps aux | grep programname`

> ps = display currently running processes
>
> a = show processes for all users
>
> u = display the process' user/owner
>
> x = show processes not attached to a terminal
>
> grep = search for a name of the process (i.e. programname)

**2. Viewing the currently open terminal session over SSH.**

Use **tmux** or **screen**. I used **tmux** and followed instructions provided in the blog run by @jacob001 and @SteveRobillard: https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141348857424/tmux-101-installing-from-source.

Once tmux was installed, as per installation guide, I tested it by running my program through it on my RPi. Then I connected to the RPi remotely via SSH using my laptop (I used [weaved.com](https://www.weaved.com/) service in this case). Once connected, I typed `tmux` in the terminal to run it and a new session opened. Subsequently, I typed `CTRL-B` then `(` to switch to the previous session (the one I initialized earlier on my RPi). And voilà, this way I could access live program's output (printed sensor values) remotely!

**Resources:**

- [tmux installation guide by @jacob001 (recommended!)](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141348857424/tmux-101-installing-from-source)
- tmux [website](https://tmux.github.io/) and [documentation](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux%26sec=1)

Comment: Would just `pidof programname` (found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13475#p141082)) work for you as well?

Comment: htop is very useful for any kind of process inspection